# How to setText in EditText from bufferreader Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, bufferedreader, settext

i have a `BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));`
the result of `buf` i want to set in the EditText.
I do it that way:

```
DecimalFormat REAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("0.##");

et202.setText(buf.readLine());
et203.setText(String.valueOf(REAL_FORMATTER.format(buf.readLine())));
et204.setText(buf.readLine());
```

It seems, that this isn't the right way, cause my app crashs.

But when I set the

```
et203.setText(String.valueOf(REAL_FORMATTER.format(buf.readLine())));
```

to

```
et203.setText(buf.readLine());
```

my app works fine. Is there a way to set a format from the BuefferedReader?

I just want that the EditText has this format: "0.00" -> show always 2 decimals like on the pic

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDMlf.png)

Comment: Do you want decimal value set on `EditText` with two decimal points? Can you share what is there in your `file`?

Comment: I already set the `EditText` to `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`
The problem is, that in the `file` are only the numbers like `5` or `112` or `4472300` inside. But my app has to show `5.00` , `112.00` , `4472300.00` and so on.

With the bufferedReader i can't do that. I don't know how to format the numbers from the file

Comment: When I use `et203.setText(buf.readLine());` the result is `5` and not `5.00`
Therefore I tried `et203.setText(String.valueOf(REAL_FORMATTER.format(buf.readLine())));`
but that make my app crash :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));       
String text = reader.readLine().toString();
et203.setText(String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble(text)));
```

Or

```
String text = reader.readLine().toString();
double d = Double.parseDouble(text);
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
et203.setText(f.format(d)+"");
```

Comment: @noobee, please share screen-shot with implementation and expected output.